# How to add custom delimiter to a list but only at a particular position?

Tags: python, list, split, delimiter

what I'm trying to achieve is given below.

I have a list

```
lst = [word1, word2, word3#word4, word5].
```

In the third element, there is a '#' so I want to split that string in such a way that the resultant list look like this:

```
lst = [word1, word2, word3 # word4, word5].
```

All other words were separated by a `,` but this is split and separated by a `#`.

Is there any built in function or a way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Lists aren't actually split by anything, the `,` is just added when printing the list or when declaring it in code. Actually only the strings are saved not the delimiter.

Comment: Yes, but is there anyway to change this default delimiter ',' to some other characters but only at a specified position?

Comment: I think you would have to save those seperatly or add them as new items in between your normal entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that prints it in the given format:

```
def printList(last):
    
    for x in last:

        if '#' in x:
            x = x.split('#')
            print(*x, sep='#',end=',')
        
         else:
            print(x, end=',')
    
    
lst = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3#word4', 'word5']
printList(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

The delimiter that you see is actually added when you output the list, python will turn the list into a string at that time.

As a result, if you wants to "Customize the delimiter", you have to modify the "turn the list into a string" function, which is actually `List.__repr__()`, just add a monkey patch to this function, and you can do whatever you want there.